# Take control of all disks/filesystems automatically in linux (Kali)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, chmod, chown

I have two mac disks plugged into my Linux Kali and for the life of me I cannot get ownership of them. (LaCie)

I don't have this problem in Windows or Mac, I just copy the files. Drag and drop.

But no matter what commands `chown`, `chmod`, any which way, these file systems are READ-ONLY.

Is there a similar right-click context menu item "Take Ownernship of" I can add in Linux?

Comment: What file system are the drives?  How did you mount them?  Exactly which chown and chmod command-lines did you use?

Answer (score 0):

If they're mac disks I assume the partitions types are HFS+, in this case you need to mount them manually in read-write mode, you will need to have `hfsprogs` installed to do this

> sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdb2 /mnt/macdisk1

Assuming /dev/sdb2 is your hard disk partition, you can get a list of partition by typing `sudo fdisk -l` in the terminal. HFS+ Journaling should be disabled prior to mounting (via your mac, open `Disk Utility`, select your volume then choose `Disable journaling` from the file menu.

If partition is NTFS, you'll need to install ntfs-3g, more info [on the official website](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/)